# “no available channels” with Ubuntu dual boot on Nexus 7 2013 deb LTE

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-7

I am trying to dualboot Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 2013 LTE, but I am unsuccessful. Some time ago, I was able to run Ubuntu on the device, but it was not a dual-boot installation.

I was able to complete everything from here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation until I've started setting a custom server:

```
adb shell "su sh 'cd /data/data/com.canonical.ubuntu.installer/files/ && echo $CUSTOM_SERVER_URL > custom_server && chmod 777 custom_server'"
```

For my device the server should be this: http://system-image.tasemnice.eu/

So, there is a file with all the permissions on the right place containing the above url. But "Ubuntu Dual Boot" app on my Android says "no available channels", although there are some.

Is there anybody who might know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Now, thanks to Vojtěch Boček, who is also behind Ubuntu Touch for Nexus 7 2013 LTE, there is a bug reported on Lauchpad regarding this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/humpolec/+bug/1379034

So, it has no immediate fix, there is a bug in the app.